# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol, however build runs OK

Tags: android, android-studio

Some time ago, I imported Urban Airship into my Android studios project.  Everything was fine until recently when it can no longer resolve the corresponding symbols.  The code runs fine, it just gives me the red errors if I open the files and so intellisense cannot resolve.

I've tried deleting everything and checking out the project again (no iml files or .idea/.gradle directories are committed), deleting my AS settings from the user directory, invalidating caches from the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up having to completely reinstall Android Studio due to having made a custom proguard jar and Android not understanding it can overwrite it and the issue went away.  This was an update from 1.1 to 1.2, which made a completely different install directory for all of the components.  I'll update if I find any more details.